# composer show with exec

Tags: php, composer-php, exec

I try this

in `var/www/shop/` I have `composer.json` and `lock`

```
putenv('COMPOSER_HOME=' . static::$root); // var/www/shop/

$cmd = '/usr/bin/composer "cd ' . static::$root . 'composer show" 2>&1';
exec($cmd, $output, $return);

$result = print_r($output,true) . ' - ' . $return;
```

the result is :

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => Command "cd var/www/shop/composer show" is not defined. [3] => [4] => ) - 1
```

If I do inside the directory : `var/www/shop/`

```
composer show
```

I have the good result

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is trying to do the directory change as the composer command, which will not work. You should be able to run multiple commands separating them with `&&`. Try this:

`$cmd = 'cd ' . static::$root . ' && composer show';`